# Unable to Sign in in Visual Studio 2019 – Completely Blank Sign In Page

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am unable to sign into my Microsoft account from within Visual Studio 2019 Preview.

I first noticed this when attempting to clone from an Azure Devops repository.  However, I get the same error in all circumstances, for example when clicking on “Add an Account” from the Accounts Settings form.

I just get a large completely blank form entitled “Sign into your account”.

I am using Windows 10 on a laptop.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Geoff Olding

Answer (score 11):

I know this was answered but i too was having the same problem and this didnt work.

First, my problem was when clicking sign in, it would bring up two tabs, one just saying this might take a minute and another saying "sign into your account", the second one would remain blank and moveable.

I couldn't find a solution on the internet, but here's my solution;

In the menu, go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Environment** > **Accounts**. Click the dropdown below "Add and reauthenticate accounts using:" and select **System web browser**

Exit the option menu and try to log in again. It should bring up Microsoft edge and let you log in, once you have it should also sync with the program.

Answer (score 3):

This issue was finally resolved by Microsoft support - I needed to reset my Internet Explorer settings (yes really, that product none of us have used for years), back to their default settings (which I hadn't changed in the first place).

Comment: You're the goat Geoff, solved my issue like a charm. My company changed the official browser to Edge and I've been having trouble not only with Visual Studio but also some pop-up based websites and other applications. Your solutions fixed a lot of problems, ty!

Answer (score 2):

In the login option page  which is displayed, click account settings (if its not displayed then click help report problem sign in option )

[image]

On the screen that get opening select , system web browser.

Now you can log in using browser and it will work fine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the top right near the 'minimize' there should be a section that shows who is logged in, or an option to log in.

Otherwise, go to help-->Register Product and select the sign-in option.

Comment: Yes, I can see that I am logged in.  When I click on the graphic showing my initials, I can choose "Account Settings".  I can also select "help" then "Register Product".  Both of these take me to the form where I select "Add an Account".  It is the form that comes up next (entitled "Sign into your account") that is going wrong

Comment: I see... yes when I go to that 'Add an account...' link it brings up a psudo-browser and had me enter credentials. If you are getting just a blank screen - it could be the connection between your computer and the Microsoft server. Perhaps a firewall or other software is preventing communication. I would open a case with Microsoft support. This is something that SO would necessary be able to fix. Reinstalling VS may also be an option.